# HTML rendered incorrectly for dynamic HTML content using master page

Tags: asp.net, html, dynamic, rendering

I have a content page which has some dynamic HTML and some static HTML. This dynamic HTML is assigned to a hidden variable in page load.

Content page HTML

```
<asp:HiddenField id = "hid"  runat="server"></asp>
```

CS of content page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  hid.Value = node1.InnerText;
}
```

This content page has master page. Below is its page directive

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/log.Master"
  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Log.aspx.cs" Inherits="s.Log"
  ValidateRequest="false" %>`
```

Below is snippet of Content page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/log.Master"
  AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="Log.aspx.cs" Inherits="s.Log"
  ValidateRequest="false" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <asp:HiddenField id = "hid"  runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>`
```

Now when content page loads, static HTML is loaded inside master page, but dynamic contents are rendered outside master page hence shows wrong rendering.

Comment: Sorry, your question makes little sense with the information you've provided. What are you doing with `hid`, where it is being displayed, please provide more information

Comment: @freefaller hid is hidden variable in Content page which is used to hold dynamic HTML created during Content page load. The HTML in hid variable is suppose to be rendered in Master form but it is shown outside the Master form. I have edited code snippet in above question.

Comment: Please learn to format your questions correctly (please [see here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help))

Answer (score 0):

The point of `<asp:HiddenField>` is that it is hidden - therefore any information contained within it should be definition never be rendered on the page.

If the contents of the field contain any HTML code that could cause it to break (such as HTML code that hasn't been encoded)... then it's possible that it will show something, but it is highly likely to be incorrect.  I think this is what you are seeing.

I'm not entirely sure exactly why you're using the `HiddenField`, or what you're trying to do with the contents of it, but I would suggest you change the following line...

```
hid.Value = node1.InnerText;
```

With...

```
hid.Value = Server.HtmlEncode(node1.InnerText);
```